# Limiting Outlook.Items object to Emails with attachments

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to limit an Outlook.Items object (objitemsrestricted2) to Emails with attachments.

I tried the following with no error messages but no filtering occurs.

```
query = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & Chr(34) & "=1"

'restrict the set to Emails that have attachments
objitemsrestricted2.Restrict (query)
```

Comment: you filter looks okay- can we see the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

In your query, use `True` instead of `1`.

Comment: I realized what the problem was.  The query is correct but I made a careless error. The statement "objectitemsrestriced2.restrict(query)" is wrong.  It should have been                            
  "Set  objitemsrestricted2=objitemsrestricted.restrict(query)".  After I did that it worked correctly.